# How to highlight matching UV vertices and edges?

Tags: uv

As of 3.5.1, my available options seem to be unsync'd UV selection — and there's no way to track what matches what in the neighbor island — or sync'd UV selection. In the later case, though, neighbor elements are fully selected and will be subject to all operations.

I need an option — be it a setting or an add-on — that will highlight selected UV vertices in the 3D viewport and (or at least) highlight neighbor vertices/edges in the UV editor, while not force-selecting these.

How are you dealing with this?